# safari and firefox now crash immediately on launch in yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: safari, macos, crash

my browsers started crashing immediately on launch on my late 2012 mac mini.

i reinstalled yosemite 10.10.1 again, and for a whole day, safari behaved perfectly. then both browsers started crashing again.

i reset PRAM, installed latest java, ran virus check, but no dice.

any solutions to this found?

Answer (score 1):

> Genieo Adware is installed.  Removing it will help.
>
> If you have another browser installed, use it.
>      If not, launch App store and get another  browser for temporary use.
>      Remove it afterwards.
>
> 1. Use  free  AdwareMedic by clicking “Download ” from here
>
>    http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php
>
>    Install , open,  and run it by clicking “Scan for Adware” button   to remove adware.
>         Once done, quit AdwareMedic by clicking AdwareMedic in the menu bar and selecting
>         “Quit AdwareMedic”.
>
>    or
>
>    Remove the adware  manually  by following the “HowTo” from Apple.
>         http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987
> 2. Safari > Preferences > Extensions
>          Turn those off and relaunch Safari to test .
>          Turn those on one by one and test.

Originally posted to the [Apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6754186#discussion-27393586)

Comment: It solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Remove Flash, reboot and reinstall Flash. This fixed constant safari crashes on 10.10.1 for me. Search on adobe.com for "remove flash" and follow instructions.

Comment: after reinstalling 10.10.1, safari was working fine for a few days. now it's crashing again. i tried the flash reinstall as you suggested, but it didn't make a difference. firefox is working ok, but i'd really like to identify the safari bug...